# How can I crack ArrayOS password

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

I have some Array Load Balance device that the user password hash like:

```
user "array"       "XXXXXXXXXVkjTX9a1kYtNo".
```

How can I crack the password or find out the algorithm of the hash?

Comment: sha-256,sha-512.

Comment: How can I find the hash algorithm of ArrayOS?

Comment: If it's salted you'll not find a match due to collisions. According to the documentation, these are the types of hashes they allow. (see page 45) http://rharrison8.com/AG%20User%20Manual/AG%209.0.1.pdf

Comment: thank you very much!Because of the weak password check I should find the algorithm of the hash.

Comment: I've reloaded and updated my answer.

Comment: Zirong - the broader question,"how can I crack a hash" has been answered extensively here, with discussion on hash, brute force, rainbow tables etc., so this question is actually a too localised subset of existing answers on the site.

Answer (score 2):

### Hashing is one-way by design.

According to the documentation for [Array Networks switches page 45](http://rharrison8.com/AG%20User%20Manual/AG%209.0.1.pdf) the only public information I found in regard to hashing indicates the following methods are supported for keys:

[image: supported hashes]

If you're talking about the initial user account on the box, it will depend on the distro / base OS they made their build from, the original settings of the build ([for instance RedHat uses Message-Digest Algorithm (MD5) and shadow passwords](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-wstation-pass.html)), and if they altered those settings. Additionally they could add a salt.

Here's a thread on [determining the distro](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-do-i-tell-what-version-of-linux-is-running-176825/). You might try to telnet to the box and that could give you and indication of what they're running (on the login screen) as long as it's not a custom distro.

Even then based on the directory structures and device naming conventions you might be able to tell what they're running (I'm assuming a flavor of *nix).

Then you might try to add another user (if possible) with a known password and try to replicate the hash that way. Some of the standalone appliances are tricky.

***Note:*** Sorry, I misread the original question. I thought this was more of a question about how to go about pulling your own password from a hash, at which point you could use a dictionary attack.